# How to reset password used for cf login

Tags: ibm-cloud

How to reset the password required for "cf login". Note that Bluemix login password doesn't work here. I think it is separate password.

I am using below command which need password and I don't it.

cf login -a https://api.w3ibm.bluemix.net

Answer (score 1):

i think it's not possible with cf or bx commands. Go with your browser to www.bluemix.net enter your id (email) and select "forgot your password" on the next page.